# .Docx file generation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

In C# I can easily generate word documents or convert word files to other formats using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, but in case the users don't have the MS office installed in their systems, I think this approach is not gonna work. I would like to know if the .net frameworks provides any specific solution for doing this. (Not interested in third party libraries, I have already found many, my question is limited to .net frameworks )

Comment: Can you save to [.rtf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) `wdFormatRTF`, *"Most word processors are able to read and write some versions of RTF"*

Comment: @Harrison: It's a good idea but the problem is that sometimes I may want to save other kinds of file formats as a word file, such as an xml document like html, well in that case this solution is not working

Comment: Thought that the runtime redistrinutable was for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608603.aspx, another option could be Office 365. Course one wonders why you are generating office documents for people without office....

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Maybe person1 demands reports in`.doc` or `.docx` file format and person2 does not use Word at all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, .Net Framework does not provide complete solution for it.

You can build it yourself starting with - [ZipPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to build final file and `XDocument` to create XML. [Office file format documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14565) is available for download.

There are indeed libraries like [OpenXml by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) to create Office documents.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to generate Office files on a machine without Microsoft Office installed without the use of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but I personally don't believe so, there's always a way

Comment: @Plexus you're right, there's always a way to do it manually.